# Panoramio Data API Returns blank JSON response

Tags: panoramio

Panoramio Data API:

I'm trying to access the photos from New Zealand through the following request of 
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=-33.541395&miny=167.380829&maxx=-46.498392&maxy=179.817352

The above URL always returns an empty content as mentioned below:
{"count":271,"has_more":false,"photos":[]}

But, the request with a different co-ordinates works fine as mentioned below.
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=-124.29382324218749&miny=36.089060460282006&maxx=-119.8773193359375&maxy=38.724090458956965

Can any one let me know, what is the problem and how this can be rectified, is the API restricted to any specific country?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The url in your example is right but the coordinates are in the middle of pacific ocean where there is no images by panoramio.

You can test it here
http://www.panoramio.com/map/#lt=-33.541395&ln=167.380829&z=8&k=2&a=1&tab=1&pl=all

One can also use this fiddle to test your panoramio requests

http://jsfiddle.net/qb0tyyjk/2/

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=-124.29382324218749&miny=36.089060460282006&maxx=-119.8773193359375&maxy=38.724090458956965',
    data: {},
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();

show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
        new Element('li', {
            text: k + ': ' + JSON.stringify(v, null, 4)
        }).inject(result);
    });
    result.highlight();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Natural feel says that minx, maxx are latitude and miny, maxy are longitude but the api seems to expect minx, maxx as longitude and miny, maxy as latitude. So, try swapping those values; meaning try to hit the below url
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=167.380829&miny=-46.498392&maxx=179.817352&maxy=-33.541395